# Applying a Linq to Entities join on my code

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have code that works, but I worked around a 'Join' in Linq to Entities, because I could not figure it out.
**Could you please show me how to succesfully apply it to my code?**

My desired result is a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, SelectedCorffData> dataSelectedForDeletion = new Dictionary<string, SelectedCorffData>();
```

The above mentioned class:

```
public class SelectedCorffData
{
    public long CorffId { get; set; }
    public string ReportNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime CorffSubmittedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Please note the 'intersectResult' I am looping through is just a string collection.

Here is my code:

```
DateTime dateToCompare = DateTime.Now.Date;
Dictionary<string, SelectedCorffData> dataSelectedForDeletion = new Dictionary<string, SelectedCorffData>();

foreach (var mafId in intersectResult)
{
    var corffIdsPerMaf = context
        .Mafs
        .Where(m => m.MafId == mafId)
        .Select(m => m.CorffId);

    var corffIdForMaf = context
        .Corffs
        .Where(c => corffIdsPerMaf.Contains(c.Id))
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.CorffSubmittedDateTime)
        .Select(c => c.Id)
        .First();

    //Selected close-out forms, whose MAF's may be up for deletion, based on date.
    var corffData = context
        .Corffs
        .Where(c => c.Id == corffIdForMaf && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddYears(c.CorffSubmittedDateTime, 1).Value > dateToCompare)                            
        .Select(c => new SelectedCorffData () { CorffId = c.Id,  ReportNumber = c.ReportNumber, CorffSubmittedDateTime = c.CorffSubmittedDateTime })
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if(corffData != null)
    {
        dataSelectedForDeletion.Add(mafId, corffData);
    }
}
```

**Please note:** this is not just a simple join. If it can't be simplified, please tell me. Also please explain why.

Comment: Simply :Dictionary<string, SelectedCorffData> dataSelectedForDeletion = intersectResult.GroupBy(x => x.ReportNumber, y => y)
     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: @jdweng : There is no reportnumber in intersectResult. I mentioned it was a collection of string. Even if there was a Reportnumber, your result would be of type Dictionary<string, string>.

Comment: I was just modifying your code which does have a ReportNumber in Corffs.  I created anonymous object in my query to make it easier to perform the join.

Answer (score 0):

The code below I don't think is exactly right but it is close to what you need.  I simulated the database so I could get the syntax correct.

```
namespace System
{
    namespace Data
    {
        namespace Entity
        {
            public class DbFunctions
            {
                public static Data AddYears(DateTime submittedTime, int i)
                {

                    return new Data();
                }
                public class Data
                {
                    public int Value { get; set; }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication23
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Context context = new Context();
            int dateToCompare = DateTime.Now.Year;

            var corffIdsPerMaf = context.Mafs.Select(m => new { id = m.CorffId, mafs = m}).ToList();
            var corffIdForMaf = context.Corffs
                  .Where(c => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddYears(c.CorffSubmittedDateTime, 1).Value > dateToCompare)
                  .OrderByDescending(c => c.CorffSubmittedDateTime).Select(c => new { id = c.Id, corff = c}).ToList();

            var intersectResult = from p in corffIdsPerMaf
                          join f in corffIdForMaf on p.id equals f.id
                          select new SelectedCorffData() { CorffId = p.id, ReportNumber = f.corff.ReportNumber, CorffSubmittedDateTime = f.corff.CorffSubmittedDateTime };


            Dictionary<string, SelectedCorffData> dataSelectedForDeletion = intersectResult.GroupBy(x => x.ReportNumber, y => y).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
    public class Context
    {
        public List<cMafs> Mafs { get; set;}
        public List<cCorffs> Corffs { get; set;}
    }
    public class cMafs
    {
        public int CorffId { get; set; }
    }
    public class cCorffs
    {
        public DateTime CorffSubmittedDateTime { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ReportNumber { get; set; }
    }
    public class Test
    {
    }

    public class SelectedCorffData
    {
        public long CorffId { get; set; }
        public string ReportNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime CorffSubmittedDateTime { get; set; }
    }

}
```